# I am having a wierd SpriteKit AdMob error that is a bit confusing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, admob

I am new to AdMob a bit so I don't know what is really going on. I am trying to add interstitial ads to my SpriteKit game and I did follow through the documentation on Google AdMob's site for implementing this ad format into my app. However whenever I try to follow it and present it from root view controller it ends up giving me an error. 
[This is where the issue currently is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvjS8.png)

I personally can't figure out what is going on. I would appreciate all the help that I can get from everyone. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load it inside your scene. `SKScene` is not `UIViewController`. You have to initialize and load the ad in the view controller that sets up your `SKView`:

```
var yourAd: GADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = YourScene(size: CGSize(width: 1024.0, height: 768.0))

    // Configure the view.
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.presentScene(scene)

    // Initialize yourAd here
}
```

Then you could hide it and show it or do whatever you want with it in your scene if you have it as a view controller property. So assume this code is inside your scene:

```
let gameViewController = view.window?.rootViewController as! YourViewControllerClass
gameViewController.yourAd.hidden = false
// or present interstitial or whatever you want to do
```